# How to make a Power BI Dashboard, in which people can filter results to their personal results with a personal ID attribute without seeing other IDs?

Tags: powerbi, report, survey

I created a survey in a survey tool. Survey participants can leave their e-mail address to receive a personal participant ID. I want survey participants to be able to use this ID to see their own survey results in a Power BI report.

I am currently building a Power BI report, in which the average survey results and the individual survey results of each survey participant are visible. The survey participants should be able to paste their ID and see their individual results. So far this is easily done with a filter. However I want to make it so that participants cannot see the other participants' IDs in the filter selection. Is there a way to achieve this?

The image shows how it should not be done. IDs should not be visible.
[image: This is how it should not be done. IDs should not be visible.]

I tried to cover up the dropdown menu with a non-transparent box hoping that participants could paste their ID and confirm with the enter key. That didn't work because they have to click the option in the dropdown.

I tried to cover up the dropdownmenu except for the first/top option. Then survey participants can see other participants' IDs.